# Indoor Positioning Map Designing in Android

Tags: maps, indoor-positioning-system, mapbox-android, google-indoor-maps

I am currently working on application for indoor positioning system using Beacons.

But my work got stuck when i have to design indoor floor plans, We have no idea how can i make maps. so, please help me about how can i design my own floor plans and use as a map.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in your case I can suggest taking a look on Digital Maps (Map Creator) powered by Indoorway. It’s a dedicated online editor for managing your digital floor plans for any physical location. You can test it out with one month for free [here](https://www.indoorway.com/tools/).